# Getting gradle related Issues while setting up project based on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, parameters, build.gradle

Project is based on Flutter and trying to run on android device.
After setting up the project, when i am trying to run the project, i am getting below error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-3.3.5/lib/src/platform_text_field.dart:578:30: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
      enabled: data?.enabled ?? enabled,
                             ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/enough_platform_widgets-0.7.4/lib/src/platform/decorated_platform_textfield.dart:536:20: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
          enabled: enabled,
                   ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

so please guide me to get solution.

So i have tried making changes in these files and even getting a pop like this file does not belong to your root directory, do you wanna try to make changes, and even simple changes as well, it is still not working, so please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the packages you're using are quite old. Please refer to pub.dev to always use the newest version:

- [flutter_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets)
- [enough_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/enough_platform_widgets)

After you've set the versions for these packages to the latest ones in your `pubspec.yaml` file, run `flutter pub get`.

Also make sure you're using the latest stable Flutter version:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```